# Hiding a DIV if it doesn't fit

Tags: css, css-float

I have a wrapper containing 3 boxes (green: 300px, blue: 200px and yellow: 100px). The container can have a width of either 500px or 300px.

What I want is that, in the case the wrapper's width is 500px, the green and blue boxes get aligned, and the yellow gets hidden (Case A). In the other case (B), if the wrapper's width is 300px, I want to have the green box in the top, and the other 2 boxes aligned together in the bottom.

Is there a way to do this?

All the heights are equal (e.g. 100px)

**UPDATE**: I cannot control in advance the width of the wrapper. So I need a solution that works for both cases, not 2 solutions (each for 1 case).

[image]

Comment: Somebody posted this link http://jsbin.com/usumag/edit#html,live , but it disappeared. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style>
            #caseA {width: 500px; float: left;}
            #caseB {width: 300px; float: left; clear: both; margin-top: 100px;}
            #caseA > div, #caseB > div {height:100px; position: relative;}

            .boxGreen {background-color:green; width: 300px; float: left; z-index: 3;}
            .boxBlue {background-color:blue; width: 200px; float: right; z-index: 2;}
            .boxYellow {background-color:yellow; width: 100px; float: right; margin-left:-100px; z-index: 1;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="caseA">
            <div class="boxGreen"></div>
            <div class="boxBlue"></div>
            <div class="boxYellow"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="caseB">
            <div class="boxGreen"></div>
            <div class="boxBlue"></div>
            <div class="boxYellow"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<style>
    #wrapper{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .wide{
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
    }
    .narrow{
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #green{
        width:300px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:Green;
        float:left;
    }
    #blue{
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:Blue;
        float:right;
    }
    #yellow{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:Yellow;
        float:left;
    }
</style>


<div id="wrapper" class="wide">
    <div id="green">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="blue">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="yellow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Then you can swap the 2 classes back and forth when you need to switch styles.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make my self clear in the post. I don't want 2 solutions, one for each case. But a solution that works for both. Imagine a user who is resizing the window from 500px to 300px.
I've updated my post.

Comment: @mossaab Well, that would have helped to know. :P  If the only condition that will result in a smaller box is a resized window, you can use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/FKDNP/5/)?

**UPDATE**: [Now](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/FKDNP/5/) using @media querys.

PS. Resize the fiddle html painel to see the result.

Comment: I don't see anything in the result!

Comment: But with this solution you will need two different classes for your container and a javascript to be checking rezises on the screen.

Comment: No, at all. Ignore container2. When you change the width of container1 to 300px, it does exactly what I need.